# Nodejs mysql how to rusults id name from table one on table 2

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm newbie with nodejs and I'm stuck right now with ...

I've 2 table 1 call example **movie** and table 2 call **categories**

I query 10 movies from movie table and in 10 movies have a genre ID from categories table.

movies: 
{
title: ABC,
**categories: 1,**
description: .....
}

This is then I results movie data but I wan to have a genre for categories from table 2 with ID 1 have a name **Action**.

I want to have something like this

movie:
{
title:abc,
**categories:1,
            {
            genre:action
            },**
description:.....
}

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you want without more information on the tables, but I'm assuming you want to join the tables. Take a look at something like the [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) for mysql here.

But from what I can understand, what you want is basically something like:

```
SELECT title, categories.genre, descriptions 
FROM movies
INNER JOIN categories ON movies.categories = categories.id;
```

Comment: This is exact what I wan, maybe can you help me more... Now I have two IDs 2, 3 in one movies what is the resolve for ?